# After creating a pod and Publishing it not installed by pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I created a pod following guides of CocoaPods.org after that whenever I try to install it in a new project it gives me this error
[image]

here is the link of it https://github.com/mozead1996/MZStoryPreviewer

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the podfile in your new project is not correctly configured.

Your pod is not officially listed in Cocoapods, so a simple `pod 'MZStoryPreviewer'` as stated in your readme file won't work.

You can either solve this issue by registering your pod (have a look [here](https://medium.com/@satishios25/creating-and-publishing-a-custom-pod-to-cocoapods-library-b314c3c7b4f0) to see how to do it) or update your podfile by specifying the github repo like so (and then you can `pod install` again):

```
pod ‘MZStoryPreviewer’, :git => 'https://github.com/mozead1996/MZStoryPreviewer'
```